# Google Play AR requires latest version error

Tags: android, google-play-services, arcore, google-play-core

I used AR for my app on Samsung M51 some time ago, and everything was fine, but when I try to use it now in the same app, I catch this error:

[image: Error:]

I try to clear cache, uninstall ARCore, but nothing works.
Does anyone have the same problem?

**SOLVE:** I just need to add this *implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.23.0'* in my build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall and install arcore from playstore

Comment: ARCore is a moving target changing every couple months, so often it has to match on both your device and development environment, but you can try uninstalling it on the device (in the settings, not Playstore) then reinstalling it. Sometimes that works...

Answer (score 0):

Add to app build.gradle

```
  //sceneform
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:assets:1.15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.31.0
```

and add root/build.gradle to dependencies this line

```
classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0'
```